# Is it possible to code a shell extension/property handler to enable editing of a directory's Comments/InfoTip via Details pane?

Tags: c#, directory, properties, explorer, desktop.ini

A file system folder can have text assigned to the `Comments` property/column via a `desktop.ini` file entry:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
InfoTip=Hello World!
```

and, in addition to populating the `Comments` column, can be added to the 'Details' tab of the folder's `Properties` dialog and the `Details` pane by editing the `FullDetails` and `PreviewDetails` values under:

- `HKCR:\Directory`

and inserting `System.Comment` in the semicolon-delimited property list. With that, **Explorer** is able to get and display the property, with the `Details` pane even *seeming* to allow editing:

[image]

But when `Save` is clicked:

- `Error 0x80004002: No such interface supported`

  [image]

So there's a "getter", but no "Setter".

So, at this point, hoping those with more experience can tell me:

1. Is this possible?
2. Where should I be focusing my attention in the MS documentation? Since there's already clearly some property handling going on, can I extend the existing functionality? Or will I need to re-implement what's already working in my own code?
3. Can this be done in `C#` or would I need to dive into `c++`?

Comment: Desktop.ini has system atrribute so its readonly, have you change this attribute before try to modify it?

Comment: @Frenchy: Yes, I have. And when creating and testing them, I don't set those, as they're not necessary -- the only critical attribute is the `ReadOnly` attribute for the folder.